# Divergence of this series and further investigation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was wondering if $1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6}+...$ diverges? I suspect that it does. I found the general term as $$\frac{2n^{2} -1 - 3\floor({\frac{2n^2}{3}})}{n},$$ which, to me, strongly suggested divergence, but I can't quite formalise the argument from there.

As a further investigation, I'm curious if there exists a function such that $\sum |f(n)|$ diverges, but
$$f(1) - f(2) + f(3) ...,$$
$$f(1)+f(2)-f(3)+f(4)+f(5)-f(6)+...,$$
$$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)-f(4)+...$$
And so on, all converge.

I apologise for the bad formatting and notation, I don't know a better way to express the question, but I can clarify anything need be. I know this is technically two questions, but I wanted to also show that $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ is not such a function, which made me curious if there IS such a function satisfying the above; if so, what are the necessary conditions a function must have for this to be true?

Comment: So its two terms added, then 1 term subtracted?

Comment: @DonThousand correct. Similar to an alternating series, where every second term is negative, this has it so that every third term is negative, the rest being positive.

Comment: @DonThousand the numerator in the general term I found for the sequence resolves to (1,1,-1,1,1,-1,...)

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya that's the sum for the alternating harmonic series, this isn't quite that.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $1+\frac12-\frac13+\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{3k-2}+\frac1{3k-1}-\frac1{3k} > 1+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{3k-2}$.

Comment: Wow, that's so simple I feel utterly dumb for not immediately thinking that...

Comment: Everything is simpler after we see the idea! No need to feel dumb. Indeed, a better answer (though less simple) is: the 1 (mod 3) terms up to $x$ add up to roughly $\frac13\log x$ (makes sense, given how the harmonic series itself grows); the 2 (mod 3) terms up to $x$ add up to roughly $\frac13\log x$ as well; and the 0 (mod 3) terms up to $x$ add up to roughly $-\frac13\log x$. You get the actual asymptotic rate of divergence this way; and it generalizes to any periodic sequence of signs (indeed of general coefficients): it converges if and only if the coefficients sum to $0$ in each period.